# Show scatter plot of change in image saturation

Tags: color, image

Let's say I have two images. One is the original and the other is after some photo-manipulation has been applied to it.

I want to show the effect on the color saturation using a scatter chart. Similar to this:

http://lh4.ggpht.com/2vp2fSsdBaP-_yvG-RIISCZbHU5-Zz1FK0lyUSo8I4iLxATq0laxzb4ha8fZz7aoFJ8sZHnc5viIC4tV-za1FxF7O7M

How would I do that?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Suppose these are `img1` and `img2` (in this example `img2` is a Deuteranopia colour blindness effect with some contrast adjustment):

[image: img1] [image: img2]

You first convert them to the `"HSB"` colour space using `ColorConvert[img1,"HSB"]` and likewise for `img2`. All you then need to do is extract the values in the Saturation channel and pair them up:

```
points = Transpose[
 Flatten[ImageData[ColorConvert[#, "HSB"]], 1][[All, 2]] & /@ {img1,img2}];

oldcols = RGBColor /@ Flatten[ImageData[img1], 1];

Show[
 Graphics[Riffle[oldcols, Point /@ points]],
 Plot[x, {x, 0, 1}, PlotStyle -> Red],
 Frame -> True, 
 FrameLabel -> {"Input Saturation", "Output Saturation"},
 AspectRatio -> 1]
```

[image]

MORE:

You learn something new every day it seems... Today I found the function `ChromaticityPlot` which can also be used quite nicely to see what image effects do to colours. Notice how the right image shows the blues and yellows have been stretched out but all other colours have been flattened onto a line (as expected from a colour blindness effect):

[image: colourgamutplots]

```
Image@GraphicsRow[
  {ChromaticityPlot[img1, PlotLabel -> "Before"],
  ChromaticityPlot[img2, PlotLabel -> "After"]}, 
 ImageSize -> 512]
```

Comment: Thanks so much! I am an absolute beginner, so I have no idea how to change the color points though. Could you help me with this too? It would look a lot prettier with the colors :))

Comment: @AmyNeville I have updated my answer, I'm also no longer using `ListPlot` but switched to `Graphics` for speed reasons.